# Can I dispatch action with 2 parameters in vuex 3?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Looking at docs
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html
vuejs 2.6 / vuex,3.0.1
do not see if actions can be dispatched with 1 more parameter, as on all these examples?
I tried to dispatch action with 2 parameters, but the second was undefined in action...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope you need to dispatch an object with a few fields, if you want a number of parameters.